# Laravel get "unique" row from mysql

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a special scenario to fetch "unique" row.

Let's say the database is like below

```
| id | userid | value | others  |
|----|--------|-------|---------|
| 1  | 111    | 10    | string1 |
| 2  | 112    | 30    | string2 |
| 3  | 112    | 30    | string3 |
| 4  | 113    | 50    | string4 |
```

what I want to achieve is to fetch the unique rows based on the "userid" so I'am able to sum all values.

the expect output row can be either `id: 1 2 4` or `1 3 4` (both is acceptable for this special case because `same id guarantees same value`, or in general, get just one row from those row with same `userid`. ), so the sum will be `90`.

Note: `DB` is extended from `Eloquent\model`

My old approach is to get DB::unique('userid'); then for each userid DB::where('userid', $id)->value('value'), add the result to sum; I just believe there might be a better approach.

Comment: `DB::table()->groupBy('userid')->sum('value')`?

Comment: @BrianThompson the DB is an `eloquent\model` that I cannot modify, so table() function wouldn't work out in this case.

Comment: @Yunhai what do u mean cannot modify?

Comment: So you named a model "DB"? In that case just remove the table. It should still work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB` in Laravel, it can return the **Query Builder**. Not recommend to use a model that is named `DB`.

So just change another name.

By the way, for Eloquent\Model, you can use `groupBy` and `sum` too:

```php
Model::groupBy('user_id')->sum('value');
```

Comment: Thx, DB is just an alias for this question instead of a specific name.